# ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut - AIR for Android

Tags: android, apache-flex, air

In an Adobe AIR application compiled for Android I am getting ANR errors with the cause keyDispatchingTimedOut. The workflow is as follows:

1. Sounds are playing, an embedded SWF is playing.
2. User presses a button - sounds/SWF stop playing
3. Application waits 3 seconds
4. Application makes some asynchronous calls to a server
5. Application handles the result, and pushes a new view to the viewstack.
6. New view appears
7. Between 5-10% of the time, after a few seconds, the ANR occurs.

Nothing in the error report really stands out. Any help would be massively appreciated. This is driving me crazy!

I have attached the ANR error report:

```
DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41b0d508 self=0x41afd9b0
| sysTid=17654 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074835248
| schedstat=( 571788091723 150929552253 787606 ) utm=48332 stm=8846 core=1
#00 pc 0000dca0 /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
#01 pc 00012e44 /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
#02 pc 00012ea0 /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+60)
#03 pc 00012f38 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_join+108)
#04 pc 001ec1ef /data/data/air.com.gameonint.matchpoint/lib/libCore.so
at com.adobe.air.customHandler.callTimeoutFunction(Native Method)
at com.adobe.air.customHandler.handleMessage(customHandler.java:22)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"Thread-3379" prio=5 tid=28 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x426bacf0 self=0x5619f470
| sysTid=21744 nice=-16 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1473838456
| schedstat=( 1340618900 149930103 2445 ) utm=119 stm=14 core=1
#00 pc 0000dca0 /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
#01 pc 00012204 /system/lib/libc.so
#02 pc 0014e913 /data/data/air.com.gameonint.matchpoint/lib/libCore.so
#03 pc 00135075 /data/data/air.com.gameonint.matchpoint/lib/libCore.so
#04 pc 001bf4a5 /data/data/air.com.gameonint.matchpoint/lib/libCore.so
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"AudioTrack" prio=10 tid=26 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x426bac00 self=0x5630d198
| sysTid=21743 nice=-16 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1473486696
| schedstat=( 835445145 754790225 27458 ) utm=32 stm=51 core=0
#00 pc 0000d320 /system/lib/libc.so (nanosleep+12)
#01 pc 0001a9cb /system/lib/libc.so (usleep+30)
#02 pc 0004364f /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::AudioTrack::processAudioBuffer(android::sp<android::AudioTrack::AudioTrackThread> const&)+402)
#03 pc 0004370b /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::AudioTrack::AudioTrackThread::threadLoop()+70)
#04 pc 0001103b /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+94)
#05 pc 0004bb5b /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+66)
#06 pc 00010bb5 /system/lib/libutils.so
#07 pc 00012e00 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
#08 pc 00012558 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder_4" prio=5 tid=27 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x424d0290 self=0x57549818
| sysTid=18326 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1458138408
| schedstat=( 15464300 14467273284 378 ) utm=0 stm=1 core=1
#00 pc 0000cb90 /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 00027fcd /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+16)
#02 pc 00016bfd /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+124)
#03 pc 000173af /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
#04 pc 0001b171 /system/lib/libbinder.so
#05 pc 0001104f /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
#06 pc 0004bb5b /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+66)
#07 pc 00010bb5 /system/lib/libutils.so
#08 pc 00012e00 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
#09 pc 00012558 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder_3" prio=5 tid=25 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42679b00 self=0x53867d40
| sysTid=18156 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1469136080
| schedstat=( 15274994 16984359588 428 ) utm=0 stm=1 core=0
#00 pc 0000cb90 /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 00027fcd /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+16)
#02 pc 00016bfd /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+124)
#03 pc 000173af /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
#04 pc 0001b171 /system/lib/libbinder.so
#05 pc 0001104f /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
#06 pc 0004bb5b /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+66)
#07 pc 00010bb5 /system/lib/libutils.so
#08 pc 00012e00 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
#09 pc 00012558 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Thread-3133" prio=5 tid=19 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4269cfd0 self=0x57f06bd0
| sysTid=17765 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1457713968
| schedstat=( 229101702 17702911370 2605 ) utm=12 stm=10 core=0
#00 pc 0000da70 /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
#01 pc 00137079 /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
#02 pc 00136e6d /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
#03 pc 0005b0d1 /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
#04 pc 000597cf /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (MessageLoop::RunInternal()+114)
#05 pc 0005982d /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (MessageLoop::Run()+16)
#06 pc 00079ef1 /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (base::Thread::ThreadMain()+188)
#07 pc 0007997b /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
#08 pc 00012e00 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
#09 pc 00012558 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"AsyncTask #3" prio=5 tid=32 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x426b3e70 self=0x56e7ffa8
| sysTid=17763 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1458082608
| schedstat=( 10809752 19933622338 363 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x426b3f90> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=32 (AsyncTask #3)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"CookieSyncManager" prio=5 tid=31 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4255f6b0 self=0x56e98d30
| sysTid=17758 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1457721768
| schedstat=( 15950658 20119845013 333 ) utm=0 stm=1 core=1
#00 pc 0000da70 /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
#01 pc 00014899 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+96)
#02 pc 00014b01 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+104)
#03 pc 000634fb /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
#04 pc 0001df30 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#05 pc 0004d183 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+394)
#06 pc 00027360 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#07 pc 0002bc68 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
#08 pc 0005f8f1 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
#09 pc 0005f91b /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
#10 pc 000544d3 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#11 pc 00012e00 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
#12 pc 00012558 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
at android.webkit.WebSyncManager.run(WebSyncManager.java:92)
at android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.run(CookieSyncManager.java:58)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=30 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42684de8 self=0x56e3c548
| sysTid=17756 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1458078976
| schedstat=( 1364349593 17478104614 14927 ) utm=109 stm=26 core=0
#00 pc 0000da70 /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
#01 pc 00014899 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+96)
#02 pc 00014b01 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+104)
#03 pc 000634fb /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
#04 pc 0001df30 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#05 pc 0004d183 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+394)
#06 pc 00000214 /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:1067)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=24 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x426783d8 self=0x57331568
| sysTid=17722 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1444187536
| schedstat=( 111962004 20480411385 9839 ) utm=4 stm=7 core=1
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x426784f8> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=24 (AsyncTask #2)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.ja...
```

Comment: It sounds as though you might be doing something time consuming on the main thread. Can you post your code?

Comment: @Kerry I don't think I'm at liberty to disclose any code but am sure that there is nothing time consuming going on in the Flex code at this point. It feels to me as if there is something going on in the Adobe AIR side that is out of my control.